# Django:How to perform a query with settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL?

Tags: django, django-models

This is my model:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    user    = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name="Company_Owner",on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    name    = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False)
    auditor = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='main_auditor',blank=True)
```

I want to perform a query which will display the list of company to which a particular auditor is associated with...

How to do query with settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL in django?

Any idea anyone?

Please help

Comment: Same as with any other foreign key. Why do you think this is special? What did you try?

Comment: I tried this `auditor_company = Company.objects.filter(auditor__in=self.request.user).order_by('id')`

Comment: `__in` takes an array (of users), why don't you just use `auditor=self.request.user`?

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this using [get_user_model()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model):

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

first_user = User.objects.first()

first_user.Company_Owner.all()  # will get all companies associated with the User
```

Comment: But I want to get the companies in which the auditor is associated with. `auditor` is a manytomany field with user

Comment: `first_user.main_auditor.all()` should work as well . or `request.user.main_auditor.all()` will also work.

Answer (score 2):

Your model relationships are badly named, change the `related_name` parameters, since they need to represent that you're fetching `Company` objects:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    user    = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name="owned_companies",on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    name    = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False)
    auditor = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='audited_companies',blank=True)
```

Then you'll be able, once you have a `user` (e.g. `user = self.request.user`) to do:

```
user.owned_companies.all()  # companies for which the user is the owner
user.audited_companies.all()  # companies for which the user is a main auditor
user.owned_companies.filter(auditor=user)  # companies of which the user is both owner and auditor
```